# Skeletal animation transfer - Orientation

Tags: python, linear-algebra, maya, pymel, skeletal-animation

I'm trying to make a pymel script in Maya where I want to transfer an animation from one rig to another. Right now the script is transferring the keyframes from the orignal rig to the other, but it ignores the joint orientation.
I have the mathematical formulas but I am unsure of how to use them in Pymel, since it's not my primary language.

The Formula: "s" is for the rig source and "t" is for the targeted rig.

[image]

As of now I have the isolated Rotation, but I am unsure of how to get the worldSpaceRotation and translatedRotation.

If anyone could help or give me some pointers that would be deeply appreciated! I can send my current code if needed.

Comment: It would help if you posted your code.  The usual beginner or intermediate level approach to this would be to do this with constraints, rather than redoing the math since doing this for every joint, every frame in Python will be a bit slow.

Comment: I think I have to use maths, since this is an assignment from school I have.